# Unable to Update Worklight studio 5.0.6 to Worklight studio 6.0.0

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am unable to update my Worklight studio 5.0.6 to 6.0.0.
I downloaded V6.0.0 Interim Fix (IF) 201307011413 from the IBM website and I tried to update the software using Eclipse's Software Update. The compressed file I tried to install is  6.0.0.0-WL-StudioP2-IF201307011413.zip. However I am getting the following errors.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

 Software being installed: jQuery Web Tools 1.0.100.v20130523_1421 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.feature.feature.group 1.0.100.v20130523_1421)
  Missing requirement: Mobile Patterns 1.0.0.v20130508_1207 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.mobile.patterns 1.0.0.v20130508_1207) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui [3.104.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Rich Page Editor - jQuery extensions 2.0.0.v20130523_1421 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.jquery 2.0.0.v20130523_1421)
    To: bundle com.ibm.etools.rpe.mobile.patterns [1.0.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: jQuery Web Tools 1.0.100.v20130523_1421 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.feature.feature.group 1.0.100.v20130523_1421)
    To: com.ibm.etools.rpe.jquery [2.0.0.v20130523_1421]
```

Can someone help me how do I upgrade Worklight studio 5.0.6 to Worklight studio 6.0.0.
The following link is the documentation on how to upgrade, it didn't help me though.
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp
The above method failed and I also tried to copy the plugins and features unzipping the update file, and that didn't help either.

Comment: What's your Eclipse version?

Comment: I recommend installing 6.0.0 in a new folder on a new copy of Eclipse. This is cleaner and allows you to keep the older version of Worklight around if you need to do any maintenance on apps that have not been upgraded.

Comment: I am using Worklight Studio Enterprise edition 5.0.6 from IBM. It's a direct download from IBM website. I did not install eclipse and download WL plugin.

Comment: I actually found a way. All the time I was trying to update my Worklight Studio 5.0.6, but I installed a new Eclipse Juno SR2 and ran the update on that, and it worked. This is weird that IBM created its update for only a specific kind of eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct version of Eclipse.
Worklight 6.0 should be installed on Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2) only.

- there is no support for prior releases of Eclipse (in 6.0)
- there will be support for future releases of Eclipse (such as "Kepler" 4.3)